# Telerik grid don't show correct item when using custom datasource

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms, telerik-grid

I got a weird problem with the Telerik grid component... I'm talking about the webform RadGrid.
I'm doing some evaluation, and right now I'm trying to use my own business logic and data layer to feed the grid (FYI, using NHibernate behind the scene).
I managed to get paging, filtering and ordering working just fine... the only thing is that what I see when filtering, is not what my business layer extracted... mmmm.
I made myself clear. Here's the code
aspx

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" AllowFilteringByColumn="True"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True"
    AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowCustomPaging="True"
    EnableLinqExpressions="True"  >
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="CountryID" EditMode="Batch" >
        <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Cell" />
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CountryID" FilterControlAltText="Filter CountryID column"
                HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CountryID" UniqueName="CountryID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Description" FilterControlAltText="Filter Name column"
                HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Description" UniqueName="Description">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="IsUE" DataType="System.Byte" FilterControlAltText="Filter IsUE column"
                HeaderText="Is UE" SortExpression="IsUE" UniqueName="IsUE">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="VatApply" DataType="System.Byte" FilterControlAltText="Filter VatApply column"
                HeaderText="Vat Apply" SortExpression="VatApply" UniqueName="VatApply">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="IsActive" DataType="System.Byte" FilterControlAltText="Filter Active column"
                HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="IsActive" UniqueName="IsActive">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Continent" FilterControlAltText="Filter Continent column"
                HeaderText="Continent" SortExpression="Continent" UniqueName="Continent">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FlgDazi" DataType="System.Byte" FilterControlAltText="Filter FlgDazi column"
                HeaderText="FlgDazi" SortExpression="FlgDazi" UniqueName="FlgDazi">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PCHost" FilterControlAltText="Filter PCHost column"
                HeaderText="PCHost" SortExpression="PCHost" UniqueName="PCHost" Visible="False">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Status" FilterControlAltText="Filter Status column"
                HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" UniqueName="Status" Visible="False">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                
            <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete this product?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                ConfirmTitle="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" HeaderStyle-Width="50px" ButtonType="ImageButton"
                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" UniqueName="DeleteColumn">
            </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

and, in the code behind I have

```
 protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        var csa =
            new CountryServiceAdv(new SqlServerDataContext(ConnStr, GeoData.Context.GeoDataContext.GetAssemblies()), logAppenders);

        var rg = sender as RadGrid;

        int startRowIndex = rg.CurrentPageIndex * rg.PageSize;
        int maximumRows = rg.PageSize;
        var countries = csa.GetCountries(startRowIndex, maximumRows, GetSortExpression(rg), rg.MasterTableView.FilterExpression);

        rg.DataSource = countries;
        rg.VirtualItemCount = csa.Count(rg.MasterTableView.FilterExpression);
    }
```

The 2 `csa`'s method work like a charm.
I don't have any other RadGrid's event handler implemented, I do everything in the NeedDataSource event.
Too bad, despite the right values I have for both `rg.DataSource` and `rg.VirtualItemCount`, in my grid I see less items. Example: given a filter for wich I extract 69 items, given 10 items per page as the grid settings, I get just 5 items in the first page and none in the next pages (the paginator works right, I have the right number of pages).
One more info. If I add this line of code in the `NeedDataSource` event handler

```
rg.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = "";
```

I get the first page right but obviously, deleting the filter, next action like pagination or ordering, will result in the loss of the filter condition.
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find in Telerik's documentation is that you may need to handle the `ItemCommand` event, or other event, and reset your filter.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-custom-option-for-filtering.html

And here are the list of events that may give you some more explanation on where you need to intercept and reapply a filter

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-getting-familiar-with-server-side-api.html